# Jenkins based automation for multiple web app project

Tags: maven, jenkins

This question is about Jenkins CI configuration

We are working on small open source project.  This project has following components:

- A1: Core Platform Web Archive (WAR)

  - A2: Social Feed aggregation WAR (It has nothing to do with A1, A2 and A3)
  - A3: Transactional Platform WAR
  - Angular UI for A1
  - Angular UI for A3
  - A3 utilizes services exposed by A1 and A2 *

We would like to do automation for testing and planning to use Jenkins.  (As of now testing is manual, and test cases are scripted in Testlink)
Here is my wish-plan

- QA team sends command e-mail to build application bundle
- App bundle has following items :
- 1 A1.war - this will be copied from predefined place (Can we specify
  it in e-mail)
- 2 A2.war - this will be copied from predefined place (Can we specify
  it in    e-mail)
- 3 A3.war - This is maven project, will be compiled, packaged    and
  copied to standard destination
- 4 UI directories are copied
- 5 Once    all of above steps are completed, one of our custom script
  should be    executed (it will prepare docker image and deploy on QA
  server)
- 6 E-mail is sent with result
- 7 QA team starts testing on testlink
- 8 Results are logged and team is notified

How should we configure Jenkins for this.  I read about Pipelines (scripted/declarative), and looks like closest choice.

Will be glad to hear openions and thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

declarative pipelines are the newest and generally-recommended way to configure your jobs if you're just getting started with jenkins (if you had started with scripted, it's not always obvious that you *must* migrate).

i think you might be talking about triggering builds based on emails. i'd recommend avoiding that and instead having your QA folks go and kick off the builds via jenkins (UI or API) and specify any parameters unique to one build using [parameters](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines).

the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-PipelineExamples) can send emails.

jenkins will log on every build so you'll have a record of what happened over time.

so you need to read a lot of docs, craft a Jenkinsfile, and keep iterating on it. there will be a bit of a learning curve, but you'll end up with your build completely codified, which will be a big help in terms of the long-term maintainability of your open source project. good luck!